# How hibernate define mapping during custom insert/update statement?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-customsql) is custome insert/update statement in hibernate. 
The syntax is:

```
insert into MyTable (colName1, colName2) values (?,?)
```

How hibernate determine

- which class field should be used for ?
- placeholders?
- Does hibernate use field names or field order?

**E.g.** if I chane colName1, colName2 order insert mapping is changed automatically or not?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you linked to:

> The parameters order is important and is defined by the order
>   Hibernate handle properties. You can see the expected order by
>   enabling debug logging for the `org.hibernate.persister.entity` level.
>   With this level enabled Hibernate will print out the static SQL that
>   is used to create, update, delete etc. entities. (To see the expected
>   sequence, remember to not include your custom SQL through annotations
>   as that will override the Hibernate generated static sql.)

So, the most reliable way is to enable logging for `org.hibernate.persister.entity` package and inspect the generated columns order before you introduce your custom CRUD SQL.

Comment: Ok, but what does it mean `by the order Hibernate handle properties`. Where to see this "property handlig"?

Comment: I think that the order is not officially documented and that you'll have to check the source code to see how it's handled.